# How do I Update an Addon Menu After Authorizing the User through oAuth via deployment as a webapp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently working on an add-on that connects to salesforce via oauth (following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SEAmNDtlcA&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers)). After the user connects, I want to update my add-on menu to reflect the logged in status (and change some of the options such as adding a logout option). How should this be accomplished? When I tried to do so during the callback of doGet(), I get an error that "The api method 'getUi' is only available in the new version of Google Sheets." I also thought of using a time based trigger, but getUI is not allowed during a time based trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both web app executions and time-based trigger executions take place outside the context of the document's UI session, and therefore can't change menus. A good alternative is to use the `/usercallback` URL and state token system for your callback instead of a web app, since this kind of execution does run within the document's UI session:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newstatetoken

Comment: Salesforce requires that callback URL match exactly when allowing access. How do I do this when the state token is different every time?

Comment: The OAuth2 spec specifically allows for a URL parameter named "state", so it should work. Have you tried it?